# What's the minimal positive integer solution to $13n^2+1 = m^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

What's the minimal positive integer solution to $13n^2+1 = m^2$?

My first intuition was that $m$ has to be $13k+1$ or $13k-1$. But how do I proceed to find the minimum solutions?

The minimum I found through computer program is $(m,n) = (649,180)$

Comment: This is an example of [Pell's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearrange $$1 = m^2 - 13 n^2$$

Continued fraction of $$\sqrt{13} = [3; \overline{1, 1, 1, 1, 6}].$$

Convergents: are m/n = 4, 7/2, 11/3, 18/5, 119/33, 137/38, 256/71, 393/109, 649/180.

checking each one we find the smallest solution is $$649^2 - 13\cdot 180^2 = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's use your finding and let:

$m=13k-1$

plugging in equation we get:

$13k^2-2k-n^2=0$

Solving equation for k we get:

$\Delta=4+52n^2$

You can see that the smallest number which make $\Delta$ a perfect square is $n=180$; for this let :

$4+52n^2=t^2$

$13\times 4 n^2=(t-2)(t+2)$

That is $52n^2$ is the product of two consecutive  odd or even numbers their difference is 4. The consecutive of 4 is 6 and that of 13 is 15, therefore n must be:

$n=6\times 15=180$

which gives:

$42\times 180^2=1296\times 1300=1684800$

$k=\frac{2+1298}{26}=50$

Therefore:

$m=13\times 50-1=649$